# How to play CS 1.6 on MacOS Catalina

Tags: linux, macos

**How do you play CS 1.6 on MacOS Catalina?**

I'm thinking about installing a Dual Boot Linux in order to play CS 1.6 on my Macbook Pro. However, I don't have the required 25 GB HDD space for Ubuntu.

Is there any other solutions to my problem, that I have overlooked?

Thank you!!!

Comment: Buy more disk space. Disks are cheap.

Comment: Yes, getting the MacOS-version of CS [steam offers](https://store.steampowered.com/app/10/CounterStrike/).

Wait: I just read MacOS stopped 32bit support and this wont work. [Don't do it](https://www.reddit.com/r/Steam/comments/df3ehp/counter_strike_16_will_not_launch_on_mac_os/)!